# Using css grid from reagent

Tags: css-grid, reagent

I tried to use css grid from reagent.

In the .css file a "container" class is defined:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #999999;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, minmax(30px, 50px));
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, minmax(30px, 50px));
}
```

And then I use the clojurescript code below to display "test" in the second row:

```
[:div {:class "container"}
 [:div {:grid-row-start 2
        :grid-row-end 3
        :grid-column-start 1
        :grid-column-end 2}
  "test"]]
```

But it does not seem to work as it appears in the first row.

Any ideas why?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try to wrap the grids into styles, like: 
[:div {:style {:grid-row-start 2
        :grid-row-end 3
        :grid-column-start 1
        :grid-column-end 2}}

Comment: Many thanks Chris Callwait. It works :-)